# Facebook Local Currency Payments Error 1383003

Tags: facebook, payment

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook Local Currency Payments with my new still-in-sandbox Facebook game.

Everything works fine except for the test payments; if I add a user ID to the Test Payers and try to open the Payment Dialog, I get this error:

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 1383003
API Error Description: Account id missing. sender: 55387993 receiver: 0
```

This only happens with the test payment IDs; regular users (or even test users) open the Payment Dialog normally.

It's strange because it says that the test users will open the test payment Dialog instead of the normal payment but for the test users I create it also appears the normal Dialog.

I've created the company, everything is working fine except to test the Payments! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, Facebook are working on it. The bug info is here: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/620035204723206/

I'm waiting on a reply as well.